# Travelling to Dubai from Berlin with a connection in Amsterdam - do I need a PCR test?

Tags: transit, covid-19, dubai, emirates

I read the [emirates travel guide](https://www.emirates.com/de/english/help/covid-19/dubai-travel-requirements/tourists/) and it says that passengers arriving from Germany do not need to take the PCR before travel.

I am travelling from Germany but I have connection in Amsterdam with a 1 hour 15 minute layover.

Does this mean I have to take the test?

I could save 60 Euros if I don't have to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per TIMATIC, the database used by airlines:

> Passengers entering Dubai (DXB) or Al Maktoum (DWC) as tourists must have a printed medical certificate with a negative Coronavirus (COVID-19) PCR test result. The test must have been taken at most 96 hours before departure of the last direct flight to United Arab Emirates. The certificate must be in Arabic or English and must be issued by an approved lab listed on https://screening.purehealth.ae or a lab accredited by the departure country.

> Exception: This does not apply to passengers arriving from Germany or the United Kingdom.

Unless otherwise noted, this means arriving directly from Germany. So you would need a PCR test taken max 96 hours before the flight from Amsterdam.